# Verifying that the click came from the specific website

Tags: php, http, security, authentication

I'm building a custom authentication process where each user who came by clicking the link (containing unique hash) at the website B is automatically logged in on website A.
The login process is not a question.

The question is about security: how to ensure that the user came from the specific website and not from any other? I can validate a variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it can be easily spoofed.
Is there a way to get the referrer IP (not the client machine IP which is in the `$_SERVER` array) or any other way to secure this process?

Comment: Whitelist the IP/domains? Have an end-to-end token which can be verified and tied to a website?

Comment: @Script47 Yes, each website has its own token. But how to get the server IP the user came from? Not the client IP, but real IP where the link was clicked?

Comment: There isn't much else that I'm aware of. You'd have to use a combination of the above.

Comment: _“But how to get the server IP the user came from?”_ - there is no such thing. They are not “coming from” any server, they are making a request in their client browser.

Comment: Yes @04FS, I am aware of that. Do you have any idea of how I can verify that this is the specific website I need? Any other way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to verify that? Once the user have the token to login to website A, the user can theoretically use the browser, connection, device it would, outside of your control. The only way is to track the user and check if obtained the token from you, but is the purpose of a token! Why check other things?

Comment: _“The question is about security: how to […]”_ - explain what _exactly_ you think is the security risk here, before you ask about how to fix it. _“came from the specific website and not from any other?”_ - how would any other website _get_ the specific hash value in the first place? I’d assume that the area where users find these links in the first place is not public, right? Are your hashes “static” and valid forever?

Comment: Right now this link placed at the hidden website part of my partners and only those who have access to that part can follow the link. But at some moment this link could become open to the whole world and everyone would be able to login using it.

Comment: @04FS Yes, the hashes are static. The client doesn't want to place any additional code on site except one link.

Comment: Well then you’re out of luck. Besides the unreliable referrer, there is nothing that would give you any indication as to where I “got” the URL from, that I am requesting from your server. _“The client doesn't want to place any additional code on site except one link.”_ - then they simply can’t expect much in terms of “security” either.

Comment: Thanks @04FS. I guess the solution here is to convince the client that the additional code is absolutely needed ;)

Comment: @slavkovl IMHO the real solution is NOT to develop something custom, instead use a standard that was developed for such a scenario, like oAuth2 or JSON web token.

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion 1

When the link is clicked on the first website store the time and user ip in a database.

When the user request is then made on the second website it can take the time and user ip and ask the first website if the link was clicked by that ip recently.

## Suggestion 2

The link on the client's site could link to a page on their site that uses PHP's [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to show the linked page. Because it was PHP that requested the linked page a user can't spoof the document.referrer. I have no idea how this would affect cookies, external references and the like.

It definitely breaks relative links.

Change the link from

```
`<a href="https://your-website.com/page/to/link/to">Click Here</a>`
```

to

```
`<a href="https://client-website.com/special-page?linked-page-url=https://your-website.com/page/to/link/to">Click Here</a>`
```

Special page on client's website:

```
<?php
$linkedPageUrl = $_GET['linked-page-url'];
var_dump(file_get_contents($linkedPageUrl));
?>
```

Comment: That seems like a solution. But for now, I want to figure out if it's possible to provide necessary security but without any integrations on the client's website.

Comment: @slavkovl see new suggestion, just requires one special page on the client's website.